# n番目のul要素の最後のli要素を取得したい

Tags: javascript, html, dom

### 実現したいこと

n番目の `ul` 要素の最後の子要素のテキストを取得したいです。

現状では `ul` 要素の最後の子要素のテキストを取得までできています。

---

### 該当のソースコード

```
var lastChild = document.querySelector('ul:last-child');
console.log(lastChild);
console.log(lastChild.textContent);
```

n番目のタグは、このように取得できることまではわかりました。

```
var nthTag = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[2];
```

これを `querySelector` メソッドの `ul` 部分に繋げる方法に辿り着けずにいます。
`ul = nthTag` を挿入して繋げようとしても、最初のulの子要素が取得されてしまうので、うまく繋がっていないようです。

答えもしくはヒントをいただけないでしょうか。

---

### 参考にしたサイト

- [要素の取得方法まとめ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/amamamaou/items/25e8b4e1b41c8d3211f4)
- [getElementsByTagName() タグ名から要素を取得 | JavaScript中級編 - ウェブプログラミングポータル](https://wp-p.info/tpl_rep.php?cat=js-intermediate&fl=r3)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[2]` によって得られるのは **`Element` ノード**です<sup>[[1]](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection)</sup>。

> #### § 4.2.10.2. Interface HTMLCollection<sup>[[1]](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection)</sup>
>
> ```
> interface HTMLCollection {
>   readonly attribute unsigned long length;
>   getter Element? item(unsigned long index);
>   getter Element? namedItem(DOMString name);
> };
> ```

`Element` ノードは **`ParentNode` ミックスインを実装している**<sup>[[2]](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode)</sup>ため、当該 `getElementsByTagName` メソッドの返り値に直接 `querySelector` メソッドを用いることが出来ます。

> #### § 4.2.6. Mixin ParentNode<sup>[[2]](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode)</sup>
>
> ```
> interface mixin ParentNode {
>   [SameObject] readonly attribute HTMLCollection children;
>   readonly attribute Element? firstElementChild;
>   readonly attribute Element? lastElementChild;
>   readonly attribute unsigned long childElementCount;
>
>   [CEReactions, Unscopable] void prepend((Node or DOMString)... nodes);
>   [CEReactions, Unscopable] void append((Node or DOMString)... nodes);
>   [CEReactions, Unscopable] void replaceChildren((Node or DOMString)... nodes);
>
>   Element? querySelector(DOMString selectors);
>   [NewObject] NodeList querySelectorAll(DOMString selectors);
> };
> Document includes ParentNode;
> DocumentFragment includes ParentNode;
> Element includes ParentNode;
> ```

```js
var lastChild = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[2].querySelector(":last-child").textContent;

console.log(lastChild);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

もしくは、 `parentNode` ミックスインが実装されていることから、単に当該 `Element` ノードの `lastElementChild` 属性を用いることでも同様のことが行えます。

```js
var lastChild = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[2].lastElementChild;

console.log(lastChild);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

---

**参考**

1. [DOM Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。進展しました。
理解が追いつくにはもう少しかかりそうです。
querySelectorのほうは、CodePen上では思い通りに取得できることが確認取れました。
ChromeでfirstChildとlastChildはうまく取得できずにいます。
nthChildなら最初も最後もうまく取得できました。
lastElementChildのほうは、これから実感してみます。

Comment: @voco さん> `firstChild`, `lastChild` は最初 (または最後) の**ノード**を取得します。一方で `firstElementChild`, `lastElementChild` は最初 (または最後) の**要素ノード**を取得します。よって、今回の場合 `firstChild`, `lastChild` を使用しても目的の動作は達成出来ない可能性があります。`firstElementChild`, `lastElementChild` を使ってください。

Answer (score 1):

### Selectors API

Selectors APIであれば、下記のセレクタを用いて実装可能です。

- [:nth-of-type() - CSS: カスケーディングスタイルシート | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)
- [:last-child - CSS: カスケーディングスタイルシート | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)
- [Selectors Level 4 （日本語訳）](https://triple-underscore.github.io/selectors4-ja.html)

### コード

```js
'use strict';
console.log(document.querySelector('ul:nth-of-type(1)>:last-child').textContent); // "1-4"
console.log(document.querySelector('ul:nth-of-type(2)>:last-child').textContent); // "2-4"
console.log(document.querySelector('ul:nth-of-type(3)>:last-child').textContent); // "3-4"
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1-1</li>
  <li>1-2</li>
  <li>1-3</li>
  <li>1-4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>2-1</li>
  <li>2-2</li>
  <li>2-3</li>
  <li>2-4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>3-1</li>
  <li>3-2</li>
  <li>3-3</li>
  <li>3-4</li>
</ul>
```